# More than one element found for locator by.repeater

Tags: testing, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-e2e

Protractor Code to access the repeater which i am using is below

```
    element.all(by.repeater('x in parked'));
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2">           
        <div ng-show="role != 3">
            <label for="parked" style="color:#0000ff;font-weight:bold">PARKED</label>
            <ul style="color:#006400;font-weight:bold" class="arriv-depart">
                <li ng-repeat="x in parked" popover-placement="top" data-popover-template="dynamicPopover3.templateUrl" data-popover-trigger="mouseenter">{{ deviceData[x[0]].boatName + ':' +  deviceData[x[0]].ownerName}}</li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, protractor throws a warning:

```
    W/element - more than one element found for locator by.repeater("x in parked") - the first result will be used.
```

---

I need to display all the elements present in Parked.

Comment: But why is this a problem for you? The warning informs you that you may need to improve your locator, but it's not an error at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple "x in parked" repeaters so the warning isn't telling you that it found multiple "x's", but that it found multiple "x in parked".

Protractor docs say to avoid Xpath, but I have found it to solve countless problems for me especially when it comes to repeaters.